# Winforms Host Javascript Content

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms

Is it possible to host and run advanced javascript, such as [this](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html), directly on a WinForms application? To be ultra-clear, when I say, directly, I mean that I cannot use a web sever to host the content and then reference by URL. I need to be able to fulfil all the required functionality directly on the form.

Answer (score 5):

Can you use an embeded html file and load that into a browser control?

Sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("hello");
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        TESTING!
    </body>
</html>
```

I named this file alertTest.html.  It's properties are:

```
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
FileName: alertTest.html
```

Then C# form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("alertTest.html");
    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
}
```

this will produce an alert box and the word TESTING! on the windows form.

Comment: That would be feasible but I'm concerned that the Javascript may need to be hosted in a webserver. Is it simply enough to embed a file and load it in a browser control? If so, then GREAT :-)

Comment: Javascript is always run on the client, not the server, so I see no reason why this would not work.  I'm 90% sure that it will work as embedded content.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll may as well give it a shot!