# WYSIWYG HTML in VB.net / C#.net

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net, winforms, wysiwyg

Recently I came to an issue in my desktop application project. My task is to embed HTML WYSIWYG in my application and here is the issue.

Most of the WYSIWYG editors are standalone apps and if I find some OS projects they are unattended from long time so this makes an issue for me (in this project I need to use OS technology which isn't dead).

Due to fact I like more web apps I know that there are (at least) plenty of jQuery/JS solutions for HTML WYSIWYG editing and this made me a question:
Is it possible to embed this code to .NET application (I cannot use ASP/MVC and project is made in **WinForms**)?

If now then maybe somebody know any good solution I could use to solve this issue?

Comment: Be clear about your (preferred) project type. Is it WebForms (ASPX) ?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, just made it clear as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should considered [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). It is the best OS WYSIWYG editor I've seen, and it is maintained regularly.

EDIT:
Here's the link to [the GitHub page](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce), there's always work going on, on this project.

Comment: I know it but question is how to embed it in Windows Forms

Comment: Are you building a web app or a desktop application?

Comment: Desktop unfortunately.

Comment: This may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299330/winforms-host-javascript-content

Comment: It is useful I must admit and I found probably way to use it but TinyMCE makes some issues with it. Anyway thank you very much for help :)

Comment: Here is a way to embed TinyMCE in Winform. I tested it and it works pretty well: https://github.com/Rocker93/winforms-html-editor